# No OpenID request was recognized in OpenIdProvider.GetRequest

Tags: asp.net-mvc, openid, dotnetopenauth

I'm trying to implement an OpenId provider using [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/). I'm using their 2 samples together, an MVC replying party and an MVC provider.

Provider hosted at: `http://localhost:4864/OpenId/Provider`

Relying hosting: `http://localhost:54347/User/Login`

I tried it with google (`https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id`), and I got authenticated. When I tried `http://localhost:4864/OpenId/Provider`. The relying party said no openId endpoint was found. When I set a breakpoint on the provider, this code returns null:

```
IRequest request = OpenIdProvider.GetRequest()
```

So the comment for when request is null is this: `No OpenID request was recognized.  This may be a user that stumbled on the OP Endpoint.`

So I guess my problem is at the provider end. What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

in the dotnetopenauth sample, when the login screen asks for a provider and you want to use the sample mvc provider, the identifier to use in your case will be `http://localhost:4864/`

and not `http://localhost:4864/OpenId/Provider`

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was using the sample MVC provider. Its [HomeController](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth.Samples/blob/master/src/OpenID/OpenIdProviderMvc/Controllers/HomeController.cs)had the `[Authorize]` attribute. This meant the xrds request failed and so an exceptions 'Sequence contains no elements' and 'No OpenID endpoint found' were reported. Removing the  `[Authorize]` attribute allows the xrds request to succeed and you can log in to a site being debugged in one instance of Visual Studio using OpenID from a site being debugged in another instance of Visual Studio.

Answer (score -1):

For security reasons, DotNetOpenAuth RP defaults to disallowing OpenIDs that start with `http://localhost/`.  For your testing purposes you can whitelist localhost so that it works for you:

```
<dotNetOpenAuth>
    <messaging>
        <untrustedWebRequest>
            <whitelistHosts>
                <!-- since this is a sample, and will often be used with localhost -->
                <add name="localhost" />
            </whitelistHosts>
        </untrustedWebRequest>
    </messaging>
</dotNetOpenAuth>
```

Comment: I even attached the provider to my local iis whose url is: `http://localhost/openidprovider/openid/provider` and when debugging, it says no open id request was found.